# Azure - Use MSAL to generate AccessToken which can be used to access BlobServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

At present, I am using the `AcquireTokenInteractive.ExecuteAsync()` function to gather an AccessToken which I can then use to ensure that user's accessing Azure are only permitted access to resources they have sufficient permissions for.

However, when I look at the ways that I can instantiate a `BlobServiceClient` object, the only way in which I can construct the object using a Token is by using the following constructors: (Uri, TokenCredential, BlobClientOptions)

Is there any way I can use the `AuthenticationResult` object that is returned by the `AcquireTokenInteractive.ExecuteAsync()` call to create an object that can be passed in when creating the BlobServiceClient that would satisfy the `TokenCredential` constructor?

tl;dr: I want to access Azure Storage using an AccessToken that has been created by AcquireTokenInteractive

Comment: You can always make your own class that inherits from TokenCredential :) Could be a good idea to check built-in implementations in Azure.Identity package though. There is a credential for interactive authentication as well.

Comment: This one could help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential?view=azure-dotnet. Full list of credentials in the package: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#credential-classes

Comment: Thanks, @juunas. I'd like to use the AuthorizationCodeCredential credential - but it requires a client-secret, which I don't have, given my app is considered to be a public client application. Does the fact I am building a public client application mean I have to use the UsernamePasswordCredential credential?

Comment: Hmm, authorization code should work in public clients as well without secrets. I would recommend avoiding UsernamePassword since then you are handling user passwords, it won't work with MFA etc. In worst case I'd make a TokenCredential class that uses MSAL internally to get the tokens.

Comment: Yeah, I would thought so too. However, when I try and instantiate the credential:

new AuthorizationCodeCredential(tenantId:tenant_id, clientId:client_id, authorizationCode:token)

I get an error saying that AuthorizationCodeCredential does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments (i.e., clientSecret is missing)?  Is creating a class derived from TokenCredential my only route here?

Comment: @Mullins According to your description, you can try to use `InteractiveBrowserCredential`

Comment: The last parameter for AuthorizationCodeCredential seems to take an authorization code returned from AAD, not a client secret. The interactive credential probably would work better here though.

Comment: @juunas when I try and compile my Class Library (.NET Framework) using the `InteractiveBrowserCredential`, any function that utilises the `InteractiveBrowserCredential` fails. Is `InteractiveBrowserCredential` invalid in this sort of context?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, I suggest you use `InteractiveBrowserCredential` credential. It will launch the system default browser to interactively authenticate a user, and obtain an access token. But, please note that the user used to do auth should have the role `Storage Blob Data Contributor` etc. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential?view=azure-dotnet).

For example

```
            var blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new InteractiveBrowserCredential());
            await foreach (var container in blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync()) {
                Console.WriteLine(container.Name);
            }
```

[image]

---

### Update

```
var cred = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
            BlobClient client1 = new BlobClient(new Uri("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/test/faces.jpg"), cred);

            BlobProperties pro = await client1.GetPropertiesAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(pro.ContentLength);

            BlobClient client2 = new BlobClient(new Uri("https://<>.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.csv"), cred);
            pro =await client2.GetPropertiesAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(pro.ContentLength);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim. Thanks for your response. Am I able to reuse this credential, without having to have the user authenticate/authorise through the browser each time? I want to fetch the credential once, and then be able to use that credential for all operations for a significant period of time (an hour perhaps)?

Comment: @Mullins you can use the method `InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetTokenAsync` to reuse the cred: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential.gettokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Identity_InteractiveBrowserCredential_GetTokenAsync_Azure_Core_TokenRequestContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Thanks Jim. This wouldn't satisfy the "credential" argument when I instantiate a BlobServiceClient/BlobContainerClient/BlobClient though, would it? I am building a desktop application that will have to instantiate one of the above everytime the user makes a specific action.

Ultimately, I want the user to be able to log on, authenticate/authorise themselves and the application, then to be able to instantiate new BlobClients/BlobServiceClients/BlobContainerClients without having to re-auth themselves?

Comment: @Mullins Yes, your understanding is right.

Comment: so if my understanding is right, then how can I reuse my InteractiveBrowserCredential repeatedly without having to have the user repeatedly auth themselves? As I believe that the InteractiveBrowserCredential credential is needed to be passed whenever instantiating a BlobService/BlobContainer/Client, which is something I need to do repeatedly in my app. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230849/discussion-between-mullins-and-jim-xu).